# Pushing to personal git repo over ssh: permission denied

Tags: git, ssh, permissions

I have a raspberry pi with a USB key with 512 gigs hooked up to my local network. I use it as my personal, private git repo, because I finally outgrew bitbucket. It works great, except...

I ssh in with the username `pi`, but my git repo has files and directories all owned by `git`. I've observed that from time to time I cannot push. I'll get an error like this:

> error: unable to write sha1 filename
>   ./objects/77/33acda0f90974cb73ad8b02fcd83896b3eeb94: Permission denied
>   To 192.168.0.2:/srv/git/writing.git  ! [remote rejected] master ->
>   master (unable to migrate objects to permanent storage) error: failed
>   to push some refs to 'pi@192.168.0.2:/srv/git/writing.git'

I've found that I can circumvent this with the horrible hack of changing permissions to 777, so clearly the issue is that the ssh user `pi` and the directory user `git` are different. New git directories (such as dir 77 in the error above) are generated dynamically by git with permissions 755, which is why I cannot write to them.

Is there a way to change the group and owner of dynamically created git directories? If I create a `git` user and use that to ssh onto the pi, will that work? What is the right way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Git's official documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc) recommends that you create a user called `git` and setup restrictions so that *"the `git` user can only use the SSH connection to push and pull Git repositories and can’t shell onto the machine"*.

You can find the documentation here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect. I set it up wrong evidently.

Comment: No worries, nice setup with the pi by the way!